# using shared_ptr with a generic registry or shared object storage...or not

Tags: c++, stl

Disclaimer; I know this isn't pretty...

So, I'd like to have a registry or shared object storage for global, shared, instances of various different classes (sub systems, managers etc.) 
I don't want to use singletons for this and I'd like to be able to have a simple registry where I can register any instance against a key and then obtain a shared_ptr to that instance later on.

Through the use of dubious casting, raw-byte views, and underhand coercion I have managed to create a class that does this, and which works (with VS 2015 at least).

I can do things like

```
myRegistry->add<FooType>(1,2,3);
....
auto shared_foo_ptr = myRegistry->get<FooType>();
```

which is lovely, but of course the code under the hood smells.

Or does it?

Here it is, I'd really like some comments and constructive tearing-to-shreds;

```
 class Registry {

    struct reg_shared_ptr_item {
        // raw byte storage for a shared_ptr of any type (assuming they are always the same size)
        char _storage[sizeof(std::shared_ptr<reg_shared_ptr_item>)];
        // the deleter will be bound to the correctly typed destructor of the original share_ptr
        std::function<void(reg_shared_ptr_item&)> _deleter;
    };

    /**
    this union is used to get access to the raw bytes of a pointer-to-member 
    since these can't be cast to anything directly
    **/
    union fptr_hasher {
        char _raw[sizeof(&std::shared_ptr<Registry>::use_count)];
        uint64_t _key_bits;
    };

    template<typename T>
    static uint32_t get_key_for_type() {
        // C++ disallows converting a pointer-to-member to a void* or any other normal pointer
        // but we don't really need that, we just need the bits which will be unique since each type 
        // has it's own implementation
        // NOTE: if the compiler for some reason or other chooses to be clever about instantiation and 
        //       it doesn't actually create a new instance for each type then this will cause collisions
        typedef long (std::shared_ptr<T>::*fptr_t)(void) const;
        fptr_hasher hasher;
        // create a pointer-to-member instance over the union so that we get access to the raw bytes
        fptr_t* fptr = ::new(&hasher) fptr_t;
        *fptr = &std::shared_ptr<T>::use_count;
        return (reg_key_t)hasher._key_bits;
    }

public:

    typedef uint32_t reg_key_t;

    Registry() = default;
    ~Registry() {
        // clean up; invoke the type-bound destructors
        for (auto& kv : _reg_map) {         
           kv.second._deleter(kv.second);
        }
    }

    template<typename T, class...Args>
    bool add(Args&&...args) {

        auto key = get_key_for_type<T>();
        auto found = _reg_map.find(key);
        if (found == _reg_map.end()) {
            // first; initialise the raw memory location to be a proper shared_ptr
            reg_shared_ptr_item entry;
            ::new(entry._storage) std::shared_ptr<T>();
            // create-assign a new shared_ptr instance
            auto sas = reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<T>*>(entry._storage);
            *sas = std::make_shared<T>(args...); //< at this point the instance count is 1
            // store off f-pointer to a properly typed destructor           
            entry._deleter = [](reg_shared_ptr_item& item) {
                reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<T>*>(item._storage)->~shared_ptr<T>();
            };
            _reg_map.emplace(key,entry);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> get() const {
        auto key = get_key_for_type<T>();
        auto found = _reg_map.find(key);
        if (found != _reg_map.end()) {
            return *(reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<T>*>(const_cast<char*>(found->second._storage)));
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    template<typename T>
    static reg_key_t getHash() {
        return get_key_for_type<T>();
    }

private:        
    typedef std::map<reg_key_t, reg_shared_ptr_item> reg_map_t;
    reg_map_t _reg_map;
};
```

Comment: You can also submit working code for critique at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: ^ And indeed should. But until then! The first thing I noticed is probably what you were referring to as a code smell: that union punning of a pointer-to-member. Alarm bells! Since neither union type-punning nor the implementation of a pointer-to-member are defined by the Standard, you end up relying on how your chosen compiler handles this situation. Which is fine if there's no other way, but usually suggests there is... ;-)

Comment: I know, it's horrible...I can't figure out any other way of achieving the same though (which is a strong indication that I shouldn't...)

Comment: Thanks for the Code Review tip @AndyG

Comment: It appears that your problem boils down to "compute a unique identifier for a type that can be used as a key in a map". C++11 offers precisely this, in the form of [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index). You should also be able to store the pointers in a `shared_ptr<void>`, and cast them back to the correct type with `std::static_pointer_cast`. No dirty hacks this way.

Comment: More or less, and the problem is also how to be able to have a single map that can hold shared_ptr's for different types. Didn't think about type_index thanks! It requires rtti though, which I wanted to avoid (for no reason other than wanting to try without)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::type_index` as the key, and `shared_ptr<void>` as the type-erased storage. Something along these lines perhaps ([demo](http://rextester.com/BEFWH40503)):

```
class Registry {
    std::map<std::type_index, std::shared_ptr<void> > registry_;
public:
    template<typename T, class...Args>
    bool add(Args&&...args) {
        std::type_index key(typeid(T));
        if (!registry_.count(key)) {
            auto p = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            registry_[key] = p;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> get() const {
        auto it = registry_.find(typeid(T));
        if (it == registry_.end()) {
            return std::shared_ptr<T>();
        }
        return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(it->second);
    }
};
```

Comment: Love the simplicity of it, and I suppose it's completely "legal" too, thanks!